# Программно получить dpi или хотя бы количество дюймов

Tags: c#, xna, .net

В одном приложении на XNA требуется учитывать dpi монитора. Встроенных способов в XNA или .NET не обнаружил, в гугле также глухо. Это вообще возможно? Если да, то как?

Comment: Почему бы не подключить `System.Windows.Forms` и воспользоваться [`Screen.Bounds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Какая ваша целевая платформа?

---
Хотя это, кажется, даст лишь количество пикселей, но не физический размер.

Comment: Физический размер не всегда можно узнать. К примеру, если это обычный проектор:)

Comment: В общем, через день я нашел неочевидный обходной путь решения задачи, где дпи не требуется. Однако все же было бы интересно узнать, есть ли способы. Это вообще первый раз, когда я сталкиваюсь с задачей, на которую гугл выдает только "линейкой померять".

Answer (score 1):

```
Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation
```

имеет нужную информацию. Куча всякого мусора включая raw dpi и scale factor.

Только сработает не на всех девайсах и не на всех операционках. На сколько я понимаю, нужно подключать нюгет UWP какой-нить.

Документация:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation

Answer (score 0):

Если вы говорите о windows, то скажу вам, искать методы для получения dpi (довольно "низкоуровневая" информация) в библиотеке .NET почти бесполезно (с большой вероятностью этого там нет). Куда правильнее использовать winAPI (так, например, .NET не может получить список всех окон для определённого процесса, с чем winapi справляется отлично).

Обратите внимание на это:
[Функция для получения DPI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shellscalingapi/nf-shellscalingapi-getdpiformonitor)

Рекомендую почитать вот тут:
[Ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12652835/getting-actual-screen-dpi-ppi-under-windows?newreg=f46de937bab14b0aa51a64fd8b5cd82e)

И вот тут:
[Ссылка](https://ofekshilon.com/2011/11/13/reading-monitor-physical-dimensions-or-getting-the-edid-the-right-way/)

P.S. C# (.NET) умеет делать внешние вызовы (принцип работы одинаков у вызовов winAPI), так что код с winAPI из C++ можно портировать на C#.